# Issue on adding Box Shadow to SVG by CSS

Tags: svg, css, drop-shadow

can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Qc3ds/1/) and let me know how I can add box shadow to svg using CSS?

I already tried these

```
.kiwi {
  fill: #94d31b; 
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 5px #000 );
  filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 5px #000 ); 
  -webkit-svg-shadow: 0 0 7px #53BE12;
}
```

but they didn't' add any shadow to the SVG

Comment: `-webkit-filter` will work (Chrome) but for the full SVG. Ex: if it was applied to `#Layer_1` for example. Placing your kiwi alone in a separate SVG might be a solution.

Comment: Something like this (not an answer - just a starting point): http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/Qc3ds/3/

Comment: @helderdarocha - this will only work in chrome, where as my answer seems to work in all the latest browsers

Comment: @helderdarocha's comment has a very important detail: **but for the full SVG**. Therefore, you have to set the filter on the svg element only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add something like the following to your svg:

```
<filter id="drop-shadow">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.2"/>
  <feOffset dx="1" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
  <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"/>
  <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

and then use the following styles:

```
.kiwi {
  fill: #94d31b; 
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8));
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc3ds/2/)